# simple layout fix for IE

Tags: theming

I'm using Omega3 and having just a couple styling issues with IE. (The site looks good in every other browser) Is there a simple way to detect IE and call an IE specific style sheet to fix these couple layout issues?

I've tried setting/unsetting css/js aggregation and clearing caches. Also tried adding this code to my template.php file and creating a ie8.css file:

```
drupal_add_css(path_to_theme() . '/css/ie8.css', array('weight' => 999, 'browsers' => array('!IE' => FALSE, 'IE' => '(lt IE 9)&(!IEMobile)'), 'group' => CSS_THEME));
```

I'm looking for a simple way to detect IE and add a couple lines of css. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1. Arguably the simplest (and least Drupal'y) way:

   In html.tpl.php:

   ```
   <head>
   <!--[if lt IE 8]>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php print base_path() . path_to_theme(); ?>/css/ie7.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
   <![endif]-->
   </head>
   ```

   Clear your theme cache if adding the template to your theme for the first time.
2. Install the module, [Conditional Stylesheets](https://drupal.org/project/conditional_styles), which allows you to add conditional stylesheets to a theme's .info file.
3. Add [37 lines of code](https://drupal.org/node/1031344) to template.php.

New to StackExchange, hope I did the right thing here. Thanks, @jdu.

Comment: https://drupal.org/project/conditional_styles   ... that'll let you do it in the theme's info file.  it's also possible to do via template.php functions.